# Appscript + GForms - Manual Run works fine, but function not recognized when onFormSubmit()

Tags: arrays, join

I hope you're well.

This script works fine when I hit the RUN button :

```
function AddRecord(first_name, last_name, email, dateofbirth, nationality, props, aei1, aei2, aei3, paeijg) {
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QW2pJY_7i-U1jhxROOtBg0usvDxI6yVdTPzkD38sD0g/edit#gid=0';   //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    Logger.log(lastRow); // Row index of last row to contain data
    var myIDCol = 1;
    var myID = dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, myIDCol).getValue()+1;
    Logger.log(myID); // Should be the value of your last record ID

    dataSheet.appendRow([myID, first_name, last_name, email, dateofbirth, nationality, props.join(), aei1, aei2, aei3, paeijg]);
```

}

Unfortunately when I submit a form, the JOIN() function on the last row is not recognized (not a function for him). This function goal is to convert the array props from a chekboxes field, to a string.

thanks nice people

I tried other fucntions to convert the array to a string, without success.